# Docker Mount Not Listing Files

Tags: php, linux, docker, file-upload, mount

I have created a new mount for uploading files from PHP application

```
/abc_datastore:/abc_datastore:z
```

When executing  the docker command: docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts}}' <container_id>

```
{bind  /abc_datastore /abc_datastore  z true rprivate}
```

But when we are uploading the file into this mount, File is not listing there. On inspecting the log we identified there no error is generated and php say file has been saved successfully there.

The surprising factor is when I do scandir($moveToDir) then I can see the file in the directory

In short PHP say the file is saved successfully. but it is invisible to me.

If anyone went through a similar situation then kindly give your hints for debugging.

Comment: I've not used `:z` before, is it something you need or have just tried?

Comment: @NigelRen I tried using rw also but it does not work. But there is another mount which is having  :z is working properly. That why I put the same